# (Vocal code) Need some help finding text-to-speech addon

Tags: java, flash, text-to-speech

I am looking for an addon that can say characters vocally. It is for non-commercial use, and it would be nice if it can vocalize more languages, like asian, english etc...
I have googled it, but can't seem to find anything for free use.

Update: This is for web use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try http://espeak.sourceforge.net/ and make an mp3 of the word, then stream it to a flash application (you could use darwin for the streaming).

Comment: This would be the way I'd go - pass it off to serverside process, then grab rendered speech file and play it back through flash.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the text to speech in Java using freetts1.2 API. It is quite simple to use. This link could be useful for you which has an example program.

http://learnsharelive.blogspot.com/2011/01/convert-text-to-speech-java-freetts12.html

Answer (score 0):

What yo uare searching for ist [Sphinx4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/html/cmusphinx.php). Some free speech models for other languages can be found [here](http://www.voxforge.org/home/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked regarding Java Text-to-Speech engines. Take a look at the question [Java: Text to Speech engines overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview#150278)and see if any of the responses are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you'll find an Actionscript 2.0 or 3.0 text to speech codebase, as sound synthesis is only just being introduced in the upcoming Flash Player version 10.

Java however has many, try [this](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php), [this](http://mary.dfki.de/), or even [that](http://www.say-it-now.com/mainsite.htm)!