# Troubleshooting "System property mbrola.base is undefined.  Will not use MBROLA voices" when converting text to speech with JSAPI

Tags: text-to-speech, jsapi

I'm getting the following error:

```
System property "mbrola.base" is undefined.  Will not use MBROLA voices.
```

```
import javax.speech.*;
import javax.speech.synthesis.*;
import java.util.Locale;

public class HelloWorld
 {

public static void main(String args[]) 
{

try 
{
// Create a synthesizer for English

Synthesizer synth = Central.createSynthesizer(
new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.ENGLISH));

// Get it ready to speak

synth.allocate();

synth.resume();

// Speak the “Hello world” string

synth.speakPlainText("Hello", null);

// Wait till speaking is done

synth.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);

// Clean up

synth.deallocate();

} 
catch (Exception e)
 {
e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}
```

Comment: @user481404 - FYI, the button with ones and zeroes on it helps format any code that you put in your question properly.

Comment: @user481404 - Also, using capitals is usually considered rude!

Answer (score 4):

For those who are still struggling with this one, here's how I got it to work on Windows in a plain notepad, no Eclipse involved.

1. I went to http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html
   and downloaded 2 packages under downloads of binary voices:
   PC/Windows and PC/DOS
2. unzip it all and put PC/Windows binary in the same directory as PC/DOS executable mbrola.exe.
   Please note mbrola.exe didn't work for me b/c it's 16-bit (go figure!), but i found this link:

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetts/forums/forum/137669/topic/1219083
   which had a zip file with 2 binaries, one from 2004 that appeared to work on my 64-bit Windows.
3. Then I downloaded the voices on mbrola website up above in section 1 I
   wanted a female voice so I grabbed us1 and put the whole folder into the same directory as
   PC/Windows binaries above and PC/DOS executable.
4. In the code i specified the following:
   System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "C:\devsrc\main\Head-Rev\src\java\freetts-1.2\mbrola");
   voice=vm.getVoice("mbrola_us1");

And I got my female voice.  I didn't need any compile or runtime flags.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

For me :

1. I downloaded [Mbrola Tool](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/bin/pcwin/MbrolaTools35.exe)
2. I downloaded [Mbrola Base folder](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/bin/pcdos/mbr301d.zip)
3. Downloaded the required voice from **Getting the MBROLA Voices**  section of [Mbrola Site](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html)
4. Unziped the file from step 3 to the unziped directory got from step2 .
5. Set property "mbrola.base" by using :  `System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "E:\\xxx\\xxx\\mbrxxx");`

Comment: Please what we must download from the step 3 and where we must install it Please ?

Comment: Site : http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html 

Scroll down , and download any voice that you want.

Comment: for the mbrola base file should we put it somewhere? :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs MBROLA app which is in the system. So you need to tell your application that MBROLA is here:

1. From command line or eclipse launch configuration: `-Dmbrola.base=/location/to/mbrola` OR
2. `System.setProperty("mbrola.base", Morbola.class.getName())` and put the mbrola JAR is the classpath.

See this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486985/freetts-problem-in-java)

(You can use any one of the solution)

Answer (score 0):

Works on Windows Systems for setting the mbrola.base: 
- set environment variable "MBROLA_HOME" in the windows os
- use this code snippet to set the property mbrola.base

public class FreeTTSVoice {

```
private static String path = System.getenv("MBROLA_HOME");
//  System.out.println(path);  

public FreeTTSVoice(){
    System.setProperty("mbrola.base", path);
    listAllVoices();
}

public static void listAllVoices() {
    System.out.println("All voices available:");        
    VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
    Voice[] voices = voiceManager.getVoices();
    for (int i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("    " + voices[i].getName()
                           + " (" + voices[i].getDomain() + " domain)");
    }

}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Because I used maven repository for mbrola instead of downloading it, I had to override this file in my java project: com.sun.speech.freetts -> internal_voices.txt and to add there:

```
# Uncomment to allow MBROLA voices:
de.dfki.lt.freetts.en.us.MbrolaVoiceDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using ubuntu 
If you are using windows you will required only step 1 and 2 .

Created a folder called mbrola
1. put downloaded mbrola-base for my operating system linux to it
2. put downloaded us1, us2, us3 extracted folders to this folder
3. Install the mbrola in ubuntu by command line.
    sudo apt-get istall mbrola

```
After installation use this commad to check where your files has located
dpkg -L mbrola
```

4. Copied /usr/bin/mbrola  file to the above mbrola  folder
5. Update the program with the path to above program
   System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "/home/ngs/INCUBATOR/egg-8/libries/MBROLA/mbrola");

Now it should work