# How to convert speech to text in java?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Can anyone share some code snippet used to convert Speech to text in Java.

Comment: hm....this is a major problem in science and many universities spend their research on this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Text to Speech engines overview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview)

Comment: @Raidri your link is about how to convert a text to speech , right ?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Check out this question.

[Java: Text to Speech engines overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview)

Comment: Wasn't the question was "speech to text"?

Comment: Yes. Trying to find ways to convert mp3 to text :)

Answer (score 5):

**Speech Recognition** is not a easy task There is a API Available by oracle.

The **Java Speech API** allows Java applications to incorporate speech technology into their user interfaces. It    defines a cross-platform API to support command and control recognizers, dictation systems and speech synthesizers.

You can view the full documentation [here](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapifaq.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx API is very widely used for speech to text conversion. You can find a simple tutorial on how to do speech recognition using sphinx in http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/sphinx.php

Answer (score -3):

It's much easier if you use python for the conversion. You can use python as an external service for your app to do the conversion.