# Text to Speech conversion in Java

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I am currently working to create a multilingual dictionary. I am thinking of adding a pronunciation feature to it too.

I need to know if there is some functionality to do so in Java. What I want is some function that takes a word as a parameter and speaks it out.

Comment: possible duplicates : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview

Answer (score 2):

If you want something closer to the proper pronunciation, you may want to try Google Text-to-Speech (assuming your application can access network freely). Although there isn't an official API it's fairly simple to use:

Simply request:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=[TEXT]
```

which will return audio/mpeg file.

http://techcrunch.com/2009/12/14/the-unofficial-google-text-to-speech-api/

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Java Speech API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/reference/api/index.html) you may want to consider looking into. I've personally never used it, but it may be a good place to start.