# How to listen(speech) text in java 

Tags: java

Does anyone know any good API or LIBRARY that can listen(speech) text. I try to listen(speech) text in three languages and I would like to know where and how is best to start. Can I use general voice for all three languages? I will use `eclipse` and `java` for language.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview

Comment: Are you looking for text to speech or speech to text?

Answer (score 0):

There is one included in Oracles JRE, [Java Speech API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html).

You might want to try [Free Text-to-speech](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) instead, to have an independent implementation.