# TTS integration in java application

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I am working on a java application which is in fact a back-office for my iOS application (iPhone and iPad)
I need to integrate TTS in my application in order to read mails content in english or french
I searched the net I found many tts engines such as festival or freeTTS but the problem that It doesn't support french
Is there any other TTS engines (free or commercial) that I can integrate in my application???

Comment: @ user2107422 ,did you got that..

Comment: no can you explain it

Comment: At the moment what you faced.. can you explain me in detail..then only i try to help you. ASAP

Comment: just tell me what framework to use in order to integrate TTS in my java application in both languages English and French

Comment: hi i updated the new link could you please click that link

Answer (score 0):

```
    private TextToSpeech mTts;
protected void onActivityResult
( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{    
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) 
    {        
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) 
        {            
            // success, create the TTS instance            
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);        
        } 
        else 
        {            
            // missing data, install it            
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();            
            installIntent.setAction( TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);        
        }    
    }
}

mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.FRANCE))
```

click this link FREETTS[enter link description here](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php)

STACKOVERFLOW already described similar to this question[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview)

Comment: FreeTTS does not support french

Comment: what happened still you faced the same issue

Comment: i am searching the net for other solutions