# libgdx speech to text

Tags: libgdx, type-conversion, speech-to-text

How can I convert text to speech in LibGDX? I was thinking about maybe it could be possible by creating somehow a function in libgdx-game-android folder  and run this function from common libgdx-game folder?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this natively inside of LibGDX. However I believe there are text to spech libraries for Java itself. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview)

However I'm not sure if this will work on Android

Hope this helps! Good luck!